# Not recognizing an integer when declared

Tags: python

When I run the code below in Python 3 (using a Mac terminal), it gives me the error *unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'*.

```
number = int
bigger = int
print('Enter your favorite number: ')
number = int (input())
bigger = int(number) + 1
type1= type(number)
type2= type(bigger)
print (type1)
print (type2)
print(  number + ' is pretty good, but ' +  bigger + ' is better.')
```

Why is the error occurring, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `number = int`, very bad code, what are you trying to do with that? Python is dynamically typed, no need for type declaration

Comment: in the last print() statement, you are concatenating integers and string (which is not possible)
Hence, just typecast the integers as str(number) + ' is pretty good, but ' + str(bigger)

Comment: The answers provided are correct.  Note that the error is really telling you call you need to know, though: there is no `+` operator for a mix of int and string operands.  If you think about it, this makes sense: what would the operator do -- assume the int operand should be cast to a string and concatenate the operands...or try to parse the string operand to a numeric type and add them?  Python wants you to make that decision.

Comment: Yea, it works now, appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Be sure to accept the answer that resolved your issue (which will put a green check mark next to it) -- lest people think that your question is still unresolved.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are concatenating different types. You can convert your number in to a string. It will be like:

```
print(  str(number) + ' is pretty good, but ' +  str(bigger) + ' is better.')
```

or can use the format method:

```
print(  '{0} is pretty good, but {1} is better.'.format(number, bigger))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating integer with string which is why you are getting the error. Use [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting).

```
    print(  '{0} is pretty good, but {1} is better.'.format(number, bigger))
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/5ADLBB) is your updated version of your code